# Matlab >>Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, polar-coordinates

I have angle information:

```
for i=1:10
   angles = func1(val);
   polar([angles 0]*pi/180,[15 0],'r');
end
```

angles is 512x1 matrix
but matlab give error on polar() function,like

Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

How to solve this problem? pls help me guys

Comment: `angles` with an `s` at the end, is that a typo? Otherwise what is it? What dimensions does it have?

Comment: it is just an variable name and 512x1 matrix one dimension
i m sorry I edited the original post

Comment: Yeah but you have `angle` and `angles`,are those two different variables??

Comment: they r same variable,I made a mistake

Comment: Your issue is that you're concatenating on the wrong dimension. Try `[angles; 0]`

Comment: where to add this one?
it give error on both case([angles;0] = func()  and polar([angles;0]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40325/discussion-between-bayanaa-and-dan)

Answer (score 2):

If `angles` is a column vector as you say (512x1), you can't concatenate a `0` to the right. You should concatenate below: replace `[angles 0]` by `[angles; 0]`.

Another possible mistake is that the two vector arguments of `polar` should have the same size, and in your case they don't.

Comment: I changed but :
error>>> THETA and RHO must be the same size.
i dont understand your second paragraph

Comment: @Bayanaa My sewcond paragraph was precisely that: both arguments (THETA and RHO) should have the same size. In your case their sizes are, at the first iteration, 513x1 and 1x2: not the same

Comment: In depends on what you intend to plot in that `polar` line. What do you want to do? Why only two RHO values (15 and 0)?

Comment: I just want to plot angles (from my function that I got angle information) using polar function

if rho have one value blue line cannot shown also with theta ([angles 0])

Comment: You cant' plot __512__ angles versus __2__ radii

Comment: I wanna plot it one by one

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40327/discussion-between-bayanaa-and-luis-mendo)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I accessed  512x1 column vectors' element one by one.